# Use of Isomorphism Theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm attempting a true/false question from a past exam paper and not sure if my approach/understanding is valid:

> If $\phi:G \to H$ is a group homomorphism and $N \trianglelefteq G$, then $G/N \cong \phi(G) / \phi(N)$

My attempt:
True, since using the First Isomorphism Theorem, we know that $\phi(G) = im(\phi) \cong G/\sim$, and $\phi(N) = im(\phi) \cong N/\sim$. So $\phi(G) / \phi(N) \cong (G/\sim )/(N/\sim)$. Then using the Third Isomorphism theorem, we have an isomorphsim from $(G/\sim )/(N/\sim)$ to $G/N$, i.e. $G/N \cong \phi(G) / \phi(N)$.

Is this a valid use of these theorems, or have I misunderstood how they can be applied?

Comment: What happens if $\phi$ is the trivial homomorphism?

Comment: Take the trivial $\phi$ to see that this is not true. We have ${\rm im}(\phi)\cong G/\ker(\phi)$. We cannot cancel $\sim$.

Comment: The statement is false. If $(\forall g\in G):\phi(g)=e$, then $\phi(G)/\phi(N)$ has a single element, but this is true for $G/N$ only if $G=N$.

Comment: Thanks, using the trivial homomorphism makes sense. Is the failure in my argument in the application of the third isomorphism theorem? Since $\sim$ isn't a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: The kernel of the restriction of $\phi$ to $N$ is not necessarily the kernel of $\phi$ so that your two $\sim$'s are not the same.